# reading multiple data models from excel and storing in a database to be used by power BI

Tags: c#, excel, powerbi, relational-database, azure-cosmosdb

I have been assigned with a project where there are around 25 excel files each with one or more work sheets. below are some of the images hw the files look like.

[image: this is one file]

[image: this is another file]

[image: another file]

[image: another file]

so the requirement is to extract all the data from the excel sheets which are in a 2 dimensional like table and store them in a relational or non relational db using c#. then the data should be presented in power BI. please help. i have been wondering for days.

Here are my problems.

1. how can i read these excel files and map to a model?
2. what type of database should i use? relation or non relational? sql server or cosmos

Comment: This question is too broad. Generally people have tried something first before asking how to do something.

Comment: Many DBMS's can load direct from Excel `.xls` files. Or save from Excel to `.csv`, load from that. But yeah, what @Noah said.

Comment: @NoahStahl , what you say is correct. the problem is i cant even think of how to do it. i dont get any idea even to try any thing.

Comment: @AntC, yes i understand that. s that is where is stuck at. please share any comments or any code that you guys have done to work with excel sheets